# A problem on Jacobian matrices

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, jacobian

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $f_1, \dots, f_m \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$.
> Are $f_1, \dots , f_m$ algebraically independent over $k$ if and only if the rank of the Jacobian matrix $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j})_{m \times n}$ is $m$?

Note that the "if" part is easy.

A example for "only if" part.

Let $f_1 = x_1, f_2 = x_2x_3, f_3 = x_1x_2x_3$.
The Jacobian matrix is $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & x_3 & x_2\\
x_2x_3 & x_1x_3 & x_1x_2\\
\end{array}
\right)$.
The rank is 2.
They are algebraically dependent since $f_1f_2 - f_3 = 0$.